# sending emails based on date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can i make conditions on sending emails to users based on date which they insert??
using if statement, without using gems.

users insert name,email and date. then based on date they inserts, system checks the date if today = date they insert + 7days then send email?? where should i type this?? is it in usermailer, or "Dop" controller???

user mailer:

```
 class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "bla bla bla"
   def welcome_email(dop)
    @dop = dop
    @url  = "blah blah"
    mail(:to => dop.mail, :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
 end
```

---

"Dop" refers to date of pregnancy

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the date (+7) into the body of the email?

Comment: As @rpedroso said, your question is ambiguous about wether you want to only deliver the e-mail if the date matches current date + 7, or if you want to change the content of the e-mail. In the first case, use my answer, in the second, use rpedroso's

Comment: i want the system to send email to users, by the date which they entered in the form then check it if the date they entered = the date now + 7 days if its true then, send that user an email,and keep sending emails every 7 days from the date he entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view, the UserMailer should only be concerned with the actual creating and shipping of the e-mail. If UserMailer is called, you should already have decided that you want the e-mail to ship.

So in your case, I assume you have a create action in a controller, which instructs the Mailer to send the e-mail. Here you simply encapsulate this action in an if statement.

```
date = Date.civil(params[:date][:year].to_i, params[:date][:month].to_i, params[:date][:day].to_i)

if date + 7.days == Date.today 
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@dop).deliver
end
```

this asumes you use something like this in your form:

```
<%= select_date Date.today, prefix: :date %>
```

Comment: More specific than this? What else do you want to know? The last block of code is what you would put in your form where the user inputs their data, the first block goes into the controller method that is called when the form is submitted.

Comment: how can i check if the system is sending??

Comment: how can i be sure that it is sending??

Comment: thnks for help but i want to understand why i should put the last line in my form?? is it to get today`s date??

Comment: Yes, it is a helper provided by rails to let users input a specific date, which can then be used in the backend, the way I explained above. See this article for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers

Comment: in (Date.civil) what "civil" refer to??

Comment: You really need to start doing your own research. I've answered your question more than once. Here is a final link, after this, I suggest you open new questions or start using google a bit more efficient: http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#M001237

Answer (score 0):

In your mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "blah@blah.com"

  def welcome_email(dop)
    @dop = dop
    @date = dop.date + 7.days
    @url = "http://www.myurl.com"
    mail(:to => dop.mail, :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

Then simply insert @date into your mailer view

```
<h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
<p>
  Something about pregnancy on <%= @date %>!
</p>
<p>
  Check out our <%= link_to "awesome url", @url %>!
</p>
```

Comment: how can i check if the system is sending??

Comment: You can [unit test](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-testing) your emails to make sure they were added to the mail queue

Comment: Try `UserMailer.welcome_email(dop).deliver` in the console. Make sure you mock a `dop` object first.